# Add a custom field to WooCommerce Billing form?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I get this code to add a custom field to the WooCommerce Billing form.

The field is shown but the problem is that the field has not *`label`* nor *`placeholder`* nor *`class name`*.

What am I missing here?
I added this code to functions.php in my child theme.

```
/*******************************
  CUSTOM BILLING FIELD
 ******************************** */
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields)
{

    $fields['billing']['billing_options'] = array(
        'label' => __('NIF', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('Your NIF here....', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'text', // add field type
        'class' => array('my-css')    // add class name
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: You can add your code for the custombilling field to the `get_default_address_fields()` function in the `class-wc-countries.php` file

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> If you are using `woocommerce_billing_fields` then you don't need to
>   specify the fields it will be automatically get assign to the billing
>   fields. But if your are using `woocommerce_checkout_fields` then only
>   you need to specify that you want a field for `shipping` or `billing`.

*For `woocommerce_billing_fields`*

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields)
{

    $fields['billing_options'] = array(
        'label' => __('NIF', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('Your NIF here....', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'text', // add field type
        'class' => array('my-css')    // add class name
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

---

*For `woocommerce_checkout_fields`*

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields)
{
    $fields['billing']['billing_options'] = array(
        'label' => __('NIF', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('Your NIF here....', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'text', // add field type
        'class' => array('my-css')   // add class name
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Reference:

- https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/1860056
- [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Comment: I doesn't work. All fields in Billing form are removed. And the new field is not added. No error is shown.

Comment: @JPashs: I have't tested my code just out form my brain, but there is logical error in your hook and array params you are using `woocommerce_billing_fields` and again adding `['billing']`, as a result you are not getting the desired output. Just replace your hook with this `woocommerce_checkout_fields` and keep your mentioned function is question then also it'll work.

Comment: I tried this: http://pastebin.com/raw/JrnHfuVT but not working yet. Can you please tell what am I missing and change the code in your answer. So that I can accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: It works. Thanks. But I created a new order filling this new field and then after I checked the order as admin in dashboard and I don't see the value sent for this field. I need to see the sent value in the order. What else do I need to do here?

Comment: The new field is neither in the Edit/user page. I need to integrate the new field everywhere: Orders, User Profile, ...Let me know if this is another question and I will create a new question. Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @JPashs, please can you share your solution?

Comment: Actually the field is saved, there is just no display of it. Adding an action for example to the admin order data will do the trick

`add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Custom field title').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_custom_field', true ) . '</p>';
}`

Comment: Hey there thanks so much for the solution! So the solution works however how would I add multiple new fields ? Only the last one is changing and I need to add like 5 new fields. Also how would one go about changing the order of the fields presented ?

Comment: Its possible add a upload file field?

Comment: @JJMontalban: Yes it is possible. I will try to provide an update ans within a day or two.

Comment: @RawalD: I will try to provide an update ans within a day or two.

Comment: @RaunakGupta Thanks alot Raunak i got it to work after some tinkering

Comment: @RaunakGupta Thanks a lot and nice code. I have found anothers tutorials with upload file in checkout but not in Woocommerce account pages (`/my-account`,  `/edit-address`, etc.). I need I have tried adding `woocommerce_account_dashboard` hook and `wp_insert_attachment` & `update_user_meta` functions. But But something fails me. I need customer can upload and edit the field himself and also be accessible by the admin from backend

Comment: Any idea @RaunakGupta?