Add / Remove Custom Checkout Fields dynamically after WooCommerce Billing section
I was able to add and/or remove dynamically custom fields (group of 4 fields by step) into WooCommerce checkout billing form, when user clicks on the "plus" or "minus" icons (see the screenshot below).

This is the PHP code that I use:
<?php
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'add_participants', 9999);

function add_participants() {   
    echo '
        <div class="billing_participants">
            <div class="billing_participants_header" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
                <h3 style="font-weight: 400">Participants</h3>
                <div class="billing_participants_actions" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; gap: 1rem;">
                    <div class="add-participant" id="add_participant_button" style="color: #1964ad; cursor: pointer;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24px" fill="#1964ad"><path d="M440-280h80v-160h160v-80H520v-160h-80v160H280v80h160v160Zm40 200q-83 0-156-31.5T197-197q-54-54-85.5-127T80-480q0-83 31.5-156T197-763q54-54 127-85.5T480-880q83 0 156 31.5T763-763q54 54 85.5 127T880-480q0 83-31.5 156T763-197q-54 54-127 85.5T480-80Zm0-80q134 0 227-93t93-227q0-134-93-227t-227-93q-134 0-227 93t-93 227q0 134 93 227t227 93Zm0-320Z"/></svg></div>
                    <div class="remove-participant" id="remove_participant_button" style="color: salmon; cursor: pointer;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24px" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24px" fill="#FA8072"><path d="M280-440h400v-80H280v80ZM480-80q-83 0-156-31.5T197-197q-54-54-85.5-127T80-480q0-83 31.5-156T197-763q54-54 127-85.5T480-880q83 0 156 31.5T763-763q54 54 85.5 127T880-480q0 83-31.5 156T763-197q-54 54-127 85.5T480-80Zm0-80q134 0 227-93t93-227q0-134-93-227t-227-93q-134 0-227 93t-93 227q0 134 93 227t227 93Zm0-320Z"/></svg></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="billing_participants_details" id="billing_participants_details" style="font-size: 16px">
                <i id="billing_participants_note" style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: 200;">You don\'t have any participants.</i>
            </div>
        </div>';
} ?>

And this is the Javascript that I use (with the onclick event).
<script>
    //Add participants number and details
    var participants = 0;

    document.onreadystatechange = function() {
        document.getElementById('add_participant_button').onclick = function() {
            participants += 1;
            addParticipantsDetails();
            console.log(participants);
        }

        document.getElementById('remove_participant_button').onclick = function() {
            removeParticipantsDetails();
            participants -= 1;
            if (participants <= 0) {
                participants = 0;

                if (!document.getElementById('billing_participants_note'))
                {
                    var participantNote = document.createElement('i');
                    participantNote.style = 'font-size: 12px; font-weight: 200;';
                    participantNote.id = 'billing_participants_note';
                    participantNote.innerHTML = 'You don\'t have any participants.';
                    document.getElementById('billing_participants_details').appendChild(participantNote);
                }
            }           
            console.log(participants);
        }
    }

    // Add new participant's details
    function addParticipantsDetails() {
        // Remove the note
        if (document.getElementById('billing_participants_note')) {
            document.getElementById('billing_participants_note').remove();
        }

        var details = [];

        var participantTitle = document.createElement('h6');
        participantTitle.innerHTML = 'Participant ' + participants;     
        participantTitle.name = 'billing_participant' + participants + '_paragraph';
        participantTitle.id = 'billing_participant' + participants + '_paragraph';
        participantTitle.style = 'border-bottom: 1px solid grey; padding-top: 16px 0px; margin: 16px 0px;';
        details.push(participantTitle);

        var inputFullName = document.createElement('input');
        inputFullName.type = 'text';
        inputFullName.name = 'billing_participant' + participants + '_fullname';
        inputFullName.id = 'billing_participant' + participants + '_fullname';
        inputFullName.className = 'form-row-first';
        inputFullName.placeholder = 'Full Name';
        inputFullName.label = 'Participant\'s Full Name';
        details.push(inputFullName);

        var inputId = document.createElement('input');
        inputId.type = 'text';
        inputId.name = 'billing_participant' + participants + '_id_no';
        inputId.id = 'billing_participant' + participants + '_id_no';
        inputId.className = 'form-row-last';
        inputId.placeholder = 'Identification No.';
        inputId.label = 'Participant\'s Identification No.';
        details.push(inputId);

        var inputPhone = document.createElement('input');
        inputPhone.type = 'text';
        inputPhone.name = 'billing_participant' + participants + '_phone';
        inputPhone.id = 'billing_participant' + participants + '_phone';
        inputPhone.className = 'form-row-first';
        inputPhone.placeholder = 'Phone No.';
        inputPhone.label = 'Participant\'s Phone No.';
        inputPhone.style = "margin-bottom: 16px;";
        details.push(inputPhone);

        var inputEmail = document.createElement('input');
        inputEmail.type = 'text';
        inputEmail.name = 'billing_participant' + participants + '_email';
        inputEmail.id = 'billing_participant' + participants + '_email';
        inputEmail.className = 'form-row-last';
        inputEmail.placeholder = 'Email Address';
        inputEmail.label = 'Participant\'s Email Address';
        inputEmail.style = "margin-bottom: 16px;";
        details.push(inputEmail);

        for (let i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('billing_participants_details').appendChild(details[i]);
        }       
    }

    // Remove the last participant's details
    function removeParticipantsDetails() {
        if (participants == 0) {
            return;
        }

        var participantTitle = document.getElementById('billing_participant' + participants + '_paragraph');
        participantTitle.remove();
        var inputFullName = document.getElementById('billing_participant' + participants + '_fullname');
        inputFullName.remove();
        var inputId = document.getElementById('billing_participant' + participants + '_id_no');
        inputId.remove();
        var inputPhone = document.getElementById('billing_participant' + participants + '_phone');
        inputPhone.remove();
        var inputEmail = document.getElementById('billing_participant' + participants + '_email');
        inputEmail.remove();
    }
</script>

Before the code was working fine. But now it doesn't work anymore (it does not even track the onclick behaviour)

This is not the right way of adding / removing fields - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341548/add-a-custom-field-to-woocommerce-billing-form . Any custom field you add and will be with condition must be not required and validated trough js or when you process the order. Check this article too - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-checkout-customization/

This is certainly because you need to switch back to Classic Checkout instead of currently using the new Checkout Block. I tested your code, and it only works (perfectly) in Classic Checkout.

I've removed the document.onreadystatechange and now it works fine. But I wonder what was the reason for it. As before this, I found that the event helps to catch the changes once the page finished reloading.
